# How can I access properties inside a symbol type object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const classRomm = {
    [Symbol('Mia')]: { grade: 50, gender: 'female' },
    [Symbol('Gilbert')]: {grade: 80, gender: 'male'},
};

let persons =  Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(classRomm);

for(let i of persons) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

In above, the `for of loop` returns `Symbol(Mia)` and `Symbol(Gilbert)`. But these are not accessible. I want to reach grade and gender property but I can not do that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the collected symbols as accessor for the object.

```js
const
    classRoom = {
        [Symbol('Mia')]: { grade: 50, gender: 'female' },
        [Symbol('Gilbert')]: {grade: 80, gender: 'male'},
    };

let persons =  Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(classRoom);

for (const person of persons) console.log(classRoom[person]);
```